# Why is t[#t + 1] = e faster than table.insert(t, e)?

Tags: optimization, lua, lua-table

I needed to know what method is the faster one because I need to insert elements in a table in a project where performance is important. I've run the following piece of code:

```
local total = 0

local mytable = {}

for i = 1, 1e7 do
    local clock = os.clock
    local push = table.insert
    local t = clock()

    push(mytable, 0)

    t = clock() - t
    total = total + t
end

print("table.insert: "..total)

local total = 0

local mytable = {}

for i = 1, 1e7 do
    local clock = os.clock
    local t = clock()

    mytable[#mytable + 1] = 0

    t = clock() - t
    total = total + t
end

print("Manual approach: "..total)
```

And it turns out that the second method runs about 2 seconds faster than the first one.

I understand that the first one is a function call, but in contrast the second one calls the `#` operator, does an addition, and then assigns an index to a value, all on the Lua side, where the first one does it on the C side.

So why is the second method faster? Are functions really that slow?

Comment: `i = i + 1; t[i] = e` is even more faster

Comment: Move the clock stuff and `local push = table.insert` outside the loops. As it is, you're probably measuring access to global variables. The whole thing gets about 3 times as fast for me. And I get 7% difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff do you mean I should keep a variable that contains the lenght of the table?

Comment: @Ihf no, as it is, it's just measuring the time taken to push a variable, and making `push` and `clock` local to the loop means they are even more accessible, because for loops do have a local storage. Notice that the time is taken just before and after the push, not including the access to the global variables.

Comment: I always think that `t[t#+1]` faster than `table.insert` because first variant uses VM instructions only but second have to use C function call. May be on vanilla Lua it is not so important but on LuaJIT it may have big advantage

Comment: Well I always tought it was faster too (whitout a specific reason) but I recently saw in a project similar to mine  `table.insert` was used so I made the test.

Comment: @user6245072 - Yes

Comment: @Egor Skiptunoff yeah of course that removes the `#` overhead... but that sound a little, you know, _extreme_.

Comment: @user6245072: How is that "extreme"? You are the one who cares about performance of table inserts in your hot loop. If you care enough to do a test, then you should care enough to do whatever it takes to get the best performance.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I doubt it would be faster to keep a variable or table field that you have to update every time you add or remove an item from an array. The loops in the example are just for benchmarking purposes. The question is not about loop performance.

Comment: @luther: It all depends on the code in question to be optimized. If the action of insertion is local to the loop, then you certainly can have a local variable that is kept up. And it would indeed be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Because function call. 
show next code. this code is based your code.

```
function insert(t, v)
    t[#t + 1] = v
end

for i = 1, 1e7 do
    local clock = os.clock
    local t = clock()

    --mytable[#mytable + 1] = 0
    insert(mytable, 0)

    t = clock() - t
    total = total + t
end
```

code works is same, but increase to one function call.

result time is 
   table.insert: 4.705

Manual approach: 4.752  <- insert function